# Filtering rows in a data frame based on date column

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
id        day           total_amount
 1       2016-06-09         1000
 1       2016-06-23          100
 1       2016-06-24          200
 1       2015-11-27         2392
 1       2015-12-16          123
 7       2015-07-09          200
 7       2015-07-09         1000
 7       2015-08-27       100018
 7       2015-11-25         1000
```

How can I throw away rows where day column is older than three weeks from today using both base R packages and other packages such as dplyr .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
 subset(df1, as.Date(day) > Sys.Date()-21)
```

Comment: subset(test_df, as.Date(day) > Sys.Date()-21) seems to be correct ,what is your idea?

Comment: @sanaz Corrected that.  I thought it was the other way.  Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Just to fill in two additional possibilities (that are nearly identical to one another in terms of syntax and quite similar to @akrun's use of `subset`).

You can use `with` in as follows to shorten the number of characters:

```
with(df, df[as.Date(day) > Sys.Date()-21,])
```

---

As you mentioned a desire to see other packages, here is one way to drop old observations using the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
# turn df into a data.table
setDT(df)

df[as.Date(day) > Sys.Date()-21,]
```

---

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="id        day           total_amount
 1       2016-06-09         1000
 1       2016-06-23          100
 1       2016-06-24          200
 1       2015-11-27         2392
 1       2015-12-16          123
 7       2015-07-09          200
 7       2015-07-09         1000
 7       2015-08-27       100018
 7       2015-11-25         1000")
```